# How to have footer fixed at bottom in Material Angular's mat-sidenav-container with router-outlet?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I want to fix ngx-audio-player at bottom of the screen like most music streaming websites.
I'm using   inside which I've  and . Inside , I've  for dynamic content and my  for playing music.

The problem is  has different heights based on the content of the link visited and  moves up-down because of that.  takes height equal to the content of the visited page.

How to fix position of  at bottom of screen (also leaving space for sidenav on left side) no matter height of

If  has more content, then only it will scroll not the

```css
.sidenav-container {
  height: 100%;
}

.sidenav {
  width: 200px;
}

.sidenav .mat-toolbar {
  background: inherit;
}

.mat-toolbar.mat-primary {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.router-link-active{
  background-color: #aaa7b4;
}

.example-spacer {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container" >
  
  <mat-sidenav #drawer class="sidenav" fixedInViewport
      [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
      [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"
      [opened]="(isHandset$ | async) === false">
    <mat-toolbar>Menu</mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list *ngIf="!anyrole">
      <a *ngFor="let item of menuItems" mat-list-item [routerLink]="'/'+item" routerLinkActive="router-link-active"> {{item | titlecase}} </a>
    </mat-nav-list>
    <mat-nav-list *ngIf="anyrole">
      <a *ngFor="let item of menuItems" mat-list-item [routerLink]="'/admin/'+item" routerLinkActive="router-link-active"> {{item | titlecase}} </a>
      <amplify-sign-out></amplify-sign-out>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <button
        type="button"
        aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
        mat-icon-button
        (click)="drawer.toggle()"
        *ngIf="isHandset$ | async">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <span  >Organization Name</span>
      <mat-form-field *ngIf="!orgName" class="example-spacer" appearance="fill">
        <mat-label >Select School</mat-label>
        <mat-select name="schoolId" [(ngModel)]="selectedSchool" (selectionChange)="refreshId($event.value)">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let school of facilitatorSchool" [value]="school.id">
            {{school.name}} 
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>   

      <span *ngIf="orgName" class="example-spacer">{{orgName}}</span>
      <span >Hi {{currentUserName}}</span>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    
      <app-player fixedInViewport></app-player>
   
  </mat-sidenav-content>
 
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Comment: please add stackbilitz for more help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by encapsulating the **router-outlet** inside a  as:

```
<div class="my-div">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Where **my-div** should set the router space. For example:

```
my-div{
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: calc(100vh - $navbar - $controls);
  max-height: calc(100vh - $navbar - $controls);
  scroll-y: auto;
}
```

Where **navbar** and **controlls** are the heights of navbar and audio player.

The important part is to set max height and scroll. So now, the whole app wont scroll, but only the content of **my-div**.

Then the router should work only inside that div. And you can properly manipulate audio-player position.

Also, if that doesn't work, try by encapsulating **audio-player** and **my-div** inside another div, which should have full size and work as a whole screen div and contain all other divs. Make sure to style correctly.

You can also, try setting the body's css to `scroll: none`, and then style divs inside to properly scroll when it's needed.